# Regarding private Container in azure storage

Tags: azure, permissions, containers, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to create a container on Azure storage which is visible only to the user logging with Admin credentials?

Other users should not be able to view the container.

Comment: Can you describe your problem in somewhat more details? Do you want the blob container in question to be visible only in your application when an administrator logs in into your application?

Comment: Hi Gaurav,In my application,on start up i am listing all the containers available under storage account.I would like to create a container say "Users" with some blobs in it,which should be listed only when admin logs in..if other users logs then "Users" container should not be listed.Hope i am clear on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish is not possible out-of-the-box. You would need to some additional work for that in your application simply because an "administrator" in your application has nothing to do with "administrator" on your storage account and Windows Azure Storage still does not support role based thingies where you fetch certain data based on the authorization.

One possible thing you could do is have a relationship between a user and a blob container somewhere in your database. When a user logs in, you're anyway authenticating your user. At that time, get a list of blob containers which this particular user is allowed to see. Then you fetch all blob containers from your storage account but only show those blob containers which the logged in user can see and are present in your storage account.

Hope this helps.